# Autowire doesn't work for custom UserDetailsService in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-ioc

The spring boot apps starts up, tomcat runs, and then it throws an error before finally dying.

## Error

Running my app gives me this `Autowired` error:

```
2016-07-29 02:18:24.737 ERROR 44715 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private myapp.MyUserDetailsService myapp.WebSecurityConfig.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [myapp.MyUserDetailsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
```

## Details

My Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/register").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout()
        .permitAll();
}

@Autowired
private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}

}
```

MyUserDetails:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;


public MyUserDetailsService() {
        super();
}

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName)
throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUserName(userName);
        if (user == null) {
                return null;
        }
        List<GrantedAuthority> auth = AuthorityUtils
                                      .commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_USER");
        String password = user.getPassword();
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(userName, password,
                                                                      auth);
}



}
```

You may find full source code at [Git Repo](http://Github.com/amingilani/spring-boot-tutorial)

Comment: I like the idea of sharing your code base via Git Repo url. It would be great if SO provides an optional Git Repo filed while posting the question, that way it would help to answer the question better by looking at full source

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've tried your project at commit `3b9a6a2e`, and the error is actually different:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private myapp.MyUserDetailsService myapp.WebSecurityConfig.userDetailsService; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Can not set myapp.MyUserDetailsService field myapp.WebSecurityConfig.userDetailsService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy80**

Which makes your question a duplicate of [Spring can't create beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33792366/spring-cant-create-beans). Solution: replace

```
@Autowired
private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
```

with

```
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
```

---

Your solution (removing `@Transactional`) works because without `@Transactional` there is no reason for Spring to wrap `MyUserDetailsService` in a proxy.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this! Although, then how would I pass Spring know to look for my config from `MyUserDetailsService`?

Comment: What does "pass Spring know" means?

Comment: I mean: How would Spring know to look for my configuration from `MyUserDetailsService`? Sorry, I make a bunch of typos when I'm typing in a hurry.

Comment: You mean, how would Spring know to autowire specifically `MyUserDetailsService`? Well, it will search for all beans that implement `UserDetailsService` (the field type), and if it founds exactly one, that will be autowired, otherwise an exception will be thrown.

Comment: @Roman, +1 for forking his repo and suggesting the fix. Indeed developers love SO and Git!

Answer (score 2):

Removing `@Transactional` from `MyUserDetailsService` worked. No idea why. If someone has an explanation, please post and it i'll mark it as the answer.

Double checked, this really is correct, if you'd like to check for yourself, please check out commit `840f0753bdca1592d9070c74bc87f30e8e2f87a7` for the repository listed above, and test it.

And stop downvoting this answer because you *think* it's incorrect.

Comment: That does not really make sense, any chances you did some edit in-between ? For example the changes UserF40 told you to do and when you tried them, your project was not rebuilt which is why it would not have worked ?

Comment: @amingilani If you readd `@Transactional` and rebuild, does it still work? If so that didn't solve it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard @UserF40, just checked, it doesn't work. Removing `@Transactional` makes it work.

Answer (score 1):

Add `@ComponentScan` to WebSecurityConfig.

This should wire in MyUserDetailsService due to [component scanning](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-scanning-components/) as it is annotated with `@Service`.

A package name can be passed as a parameter to the annotation to set the scope of component scanning, for example:

```
@ComponentScan("com.company.team")
```

Comment: This is not really a good fix. You are hiding the fact that the bean is not scanned.

Comment: @Service beans are also scanned. And the fact that scanning is not used *is* the real problem.

Comment: Note that if basePackageClasses is not defined in @ComponentScan, the scan will occurs from the package of the class that declares the annotation.

Comment: Didn't work. Added `@ComponentScan`, as well as `@ComponentScan("myapp")`, and `@ComponentScan("myapp.MyUserDetailsService")`

Comment: Why don't the package declarations in your v2 project on github match the directory structure of where the file is?

Comment: @UserF40 `myapp`, I seem to have fixed it, no idea why though. Check the other answer.

Comment: @UserF40 because I learnt Java last weekend, and I'm from the Nodejs world where we don't bundle everything into packages. Thank you for pointing it out! I'll do that next :)

Answer (score 1):

please add Annotation: `@ComponentScan("")`
on main configuration class.

If you want to create bean/service for specific directory then you can give package path inside `@ComponentScan("package.to.scan")`